# nginx service is showing failed status

Tags: nginx, centos7, wsl-2

I have installed the `nginx` server on `CentOS7` on `WSL2`. Followed the instructions on https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-nginx-on-centos-7/ when I start the server using `service nginx start` it doesn't gives me any error, but when I run `service nginx status` it gives me following error
`[root@nasth-azvm5 AshishTyagi]# service nginx status Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status nginx.service nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service, enabled) Active: failed (dead)`

so I looked at the logs at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` the logs are appearing as
`2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27549#27549: using the "epoll" event method 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27549#27549: nginx/1.24.0 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27549#27549: built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27549#27549: OS: Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27549#27549: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:1048576 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker processes 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker process 27551 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker process 27552 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker process 27553 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker process 27554 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker process 27555 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker process 27556 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker process 27557 2023/04/20 16:08:50 [notice] 27550#27550: start worker process 27558`

I have looked the solution at stackoverflow but that did not work. What else can I do to debug and fix this issue. Please help.

I have try to find the solution on internet, google and stackoverflow, if I can find some more logs I can try to fix the issue but nothing help.
[service nginx start getting failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811731/service-nginx-start-getting-failed)